# Timetable same size error, but are same size

Tags: matlab, timetable, control-theory

I have data from three different timelines (from two different times of different days) and my goal ist to use tfest later to estimate a transfer function. Therefor i have to make them the same length and ideally give them a new timeline so I can plot them later in one graph. Here is my take at it:

```
% Auffüllen der kürzeren Zeitachsen mit den letzten Werten
if length(timeline_1) < max_timeline
    zeitachse_1 = linspace(timeline_1(1), timeline_1(end), max_timeline);
    daten_1 = [daten_1; repmat(daten_1(end,:), max_timeline - length(daten_1), 1)];
end

if length(timeline_2) < max_timeline
    timeline_2 = linspace(timeline_2(1), timeline_2(end), max_timeline);
    daten_2 = [daten_2; repmat(daten_2(end,:), max_timeline - length(daten_2), 1)];
end

if length(timeline_3) < max_timeline
    timeline_3 = linspace(timeline_3(1), timeline_3(end), max_timeline);
    daten_3 = [daten_3; repmat(daten_3(end,:), max_timeline - length(daten_3), 1)];
end

% Erstellen von neuen Timetables mit den modifizierten Zeitachsen und Daten
T_1 = timetable(timeline_1, daten_1(:, 1), daten_1(:, 2), daten_1(:, 3));
```

The result is this:

```
>> length(daten_1(:,1))

ans =

      113997

>> length(daten_1(:,2))

ans =

      113997

>> length(daten_1(:,3))

ans =

      113997

>> length(timeline_1)

ans =

      113997
```

Yet I get this error:

```
Error using timetable (line 317)
All table variables must have the same number of rows.

Error in test (line 135)
T_1 = timetable(timeline_1, daten_1(:, 1), daten_1(:, 2), daten_1(:, 3));
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is `timeline_1` a row or a column vector? Don't use `length` to check sizes, instead, use `size()`.

Comment: timeline_1 = T_1.Time - T_1.Time(1); --- T_1 is a timetable and timeline_1 is created in this way

Comment: All fine, but what is its size? As I asked you, is it a row or a column matrix? i.e. is its size `113997 1` or `1 113997`? This is exactly why you should use `size()` rather than `length()`, as `length()` will return only the maximum dimension of your matrix, rather than all. Thus, `lentgh(a)` is equivalent to `max(size(A))`.

Comment: Ohh thank you, now I get it. The timeline is 1 113997 and the data is 113997 1. How do I fix this?

Comment: Transpose it. See the duplicate; use `.'` .

Comment: This works for the first two, but not for the last third. Any further ideas?